# Linking a table view to the edit button with user info already in place using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, edit

I have an edit button (revealed when user swipes right) that I'm trying to link to the below table view but with the user information already in the fields. How would I go about doing something like that?

I imagine it has something to do with this piece but everything I have tried isn't working:

```
let newRelease = Release_Date(context: context)
newRelease.artist = artist
newRelease.album = album
newRelease.release_date = releasedate as NSDate?
newRelease.release_dateId = UUID().uuidString
```

Below is the table view code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class AddfreshreleaseViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var artisttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var albumtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var releasedatePicker: UIDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    releasedatePicker.minimumDate = Date()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func saveTapped( _ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let artist = artisttextfield.text ?? ""
    let album = albumtextfield.text ?? ""
    let releasedate = releasedatePicker.date

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newRelease = Release_Date(context: context)
    newRelease.artist = artist
    newRelease.album = album
    newRelease.release_date = releasedate as NSDate?
    newRelease.release_dateId = UUID().uuidString

    if let uniqueId = newRelease.release_dateId {
        print("The freshreleaseId is \(uniqueId)")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        let message = "\(artist)'s new album \(album) releases Today!"
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day],
            from: releasedate)
        dateComponents.hour = 09
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
            repeats: true)
        if let identifier = newRelease.release_dateId {

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not save because of \(error).")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Added a Release Date!")
    print("Artist: \(newRelease.artist)")
    print("Album: \(newRelease.album)")
    print("Release Date: \(newRelease.release_date)")
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide additional context for reference? For example, do you want the edit button to set the table view into editing mode?

Comment: I want the edit button to go back to where the user entered the information for the cell. As of right now, swiping one way shows the delete button, swiping the other way shows the edit button. But the edit button does nothing, I can't figure out how to make it go back to where the user puts in their information.